# How to get touchpad working again?

Tags: 18.04, touchpad

The touchpad on my Dell laptop, running 18.04 LTS, stopped working.  In Devices, the touchpad is listed as ON.  I have tried rebooting, updating and upgrading, and using Time Shift to restore the system to a previous state.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Normally there is a key switching the touchpad on and off – did you check that already?

Comment: For now, use an external mouse or the previous kernel (4.15.0-70) as suggested in [comment #7](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1854798/comments/7) or read the [full bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1854798).